# If cell is empty, don't auto fill data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I currently have a range of cells that concatenates a date and time and produces something along the lines of this

```
   ______A________
1 | 9/1/12 2:00 AM
2 | 9/4/12 2:00 AM
3 |    NULL
```

In the B column I have the following formulas `=A1` `=A2` and so on.

On cell `B3` the value is `1/0/00 12:00 AM` due to the fact that `A3` is an empty cell. Is there a way to make it so that if the cell in question is empty, it returns a blank value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the formula to something slightly more complex

```
=IF(A1="", "", A1)
```

if a1 is empty, then display an empty string, otherwise the value in a1.

Comment: This is perfect! Had to use double quotes, though I'm not sure why. Will give it the checkmark as soon as it lets me